# Calling Jquery mobile function on View html to move Back and Next

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two views files one is for product and second is for booking. Here is my script that I want to call between the view pages to go back and forth on pressing the back and next button. Please tell me how to do it. Thank you.

Script.js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.showNextPage', function() {
  $.mobile.navigate('#second', {
    transition: "slide"
  });
});

$(document).on('click', '.showPrevPage', function() {
  $.mobile.navigate("#index", {
    transition: "slide"
  });
});
```

Booking View Index.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}
@{ViewGenerator vg = new ViewGenerator();
  CartInfo cartInfo = vg.GetBookingCartInfo();


    @section head{
        @Url.ScriptRender(BundleResources.BOOKIGN_SCRIPT)

        @{if (DffUtility.SalesChannelID == 2)
          {
            <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
            <script>
                var google_tag_params =
                {
                    hrental_id: '@cartInfo.ProdId',
                        hrental_pagetype: 'conversionintent',
                        hrental_startdate: '@cartInfo.StartDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")',
                        hrental_enddate: '@cartInfo.EndDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")',
                        hrental_totalvalue: '@cartInfo.TotalPrice'
                    }
            </script>

            <noscript>
                <iframe src='//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-NMVP7S' height='0' width='0' style='display: none; visibility: hidden'></iframe>
            </noscript>
            <script>(function (w, d, s, l, i) { w[l] = w[l] || []; w[l].push({ 'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(), event: 'gtm.js' }); var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], j = d.createElement(s), dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : ''; j.async = true; j.src = '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl; f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f); })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-NMVP7S');</script>
            <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
          }
        }

        <!-- Advertiser 'Advantage Media Aps', Exclude user from segment 'Friferie 1. reg step Re-Targeting' -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var pixelSRCType = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://" : "http://");
            var cId = '299f5c2b-2920-4888-acc7-37be7f8a9d28';
            var tName = 'basket';
            var pId = '@cartInfo.ProdId'; // Insert comma seperated string of productid/ids 
                var revenue = '';
                var orderId = '';
                var p1 = '';
                var p2 = '';
                var p3 = '';

                document.write("<iframe src='" + pixelSRCType + "adserver.adnexio.com/Tracking/EventHandler?cId=" + cId + "&tName=" + tName + "&pId=" + pId + "&revenue=" + revenue + "&orderId=" + orderId + "&p1=" + p1 + "&p2=" + p2 + "&p3=" + p3 + "' allowtransparency='true' framespacing='0' frameborder='no' scrolling='no' width='0' height='0'></iframe>");
        </script>
        <!-- End of segment tag -->


    }

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var LoadCustomerInfo_Url, SaveBooking_Url, SendEmail_Url, CartInfo_Url, TENWEB_PATH, SeeMoreText, BOOKING_FORM, TellHome, Fax, PhoneHome, COAddress, City, Country,
            CUSTOMER_INFO, BASIC_MESSAGE, BASIC_RULE, IsPartialPayment;

        LoadCustomerInfo_Url = '@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}/Booking.aspx/LoadCustomerInfo?{1}", ConfigurationSettings.TENWEB_PATH, Request.QueryString))';
        SaveBooking_Url = '@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}/Booking.aspx/SaveBooking?{1}", ConfigurationSettings.TENWEB_PATH, Request.QueryString))';
        SendEmail_Url = '@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}/Booking.aspx/SendErrorEmail?{1}", ConfigurationSettings.TENWEB_PATH, Request.QueryString))';
        CartInfo_Url = '@Html.Raw(string.Format("{0}/Booking.aspx/LoadCartItems?{1}", ConfigurationSettings.TENWEB_PATH, Request.QueryString))';
        TENWEB_PATH = '@Html.Raw(ConfigurationSettings.TENWEB_PATH)';
        SeeMoreText = '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("SeeMore"))';
        IsPartialPayment = '@cartInfo.IsPartialPayment.ToString().ToLower()';

        BASIC_MESSAGE = {
            FName: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("FirstNameErrorText"))',
            LName: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("LastNameErrorText"))',
            Email: {
                required: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("EmailErrorText"))',
                email: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("EnterYourEmailErrorText"))'
            },
            Email2: {
                required: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("ConfirmEmailErrorText"))',
                equalTo: "@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("ConfirmEmailNotMatchText"))",
                email: "@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("EnterConfirmEmailErrorText"))"
            },
            Address: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("AddressErrorText"))',
            PostNo: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("PostNoErrorText"))',
            MobileNo: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("MobileNoErrorText"))',
            ddlCancellationInsurance: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("CancellationInsuranceErrorText"))',
            ddlCardTypes: '@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("SelectCardType"))'
        }
    </script>
    <div class="bestilling">
        <form action="">
            <div class="bestilling_i">
                <h2>@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("OrderingOfHoliday"))</h2>
                <div class="bestilling-wrap pb17">
                    <div class="bestilling__col bestilling_Align">

                        <div class="row-sel">
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("Email"))" id="Email" name="Email" onchange="LoadCustomerInfo()">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("FirstName"))" id="FName" name="FName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("Address"))" id="Address" name="Address">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("MobileNo"))" id="MobileNo" name="MobileNo">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--bestilling__col end-->
                    <div class="bestilling__col bestilling_Align">
                        <div class="row-sel">
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="email" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("ConfirmEmail"))" id="Email2" name="Email2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("LastName"))" id="LName" name="LName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inp">
                                <input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("PostNo"))"  id="PostNo" name="PostNo">
                            </div>
                            @*<div class="inp">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("PromoCode"))"  id="PromoCode" name="PromoCode">
                            </div>*@
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--bestilling__col end-->
                    <div class="clear-both"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="bestilling-wrap">
                    <h3>@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("DimensionsAndAcquisitions"))</h3>
                </div>
                @{if (cartInfo.IsCancellationInsuranceEnable)
                  {
                    <div class="bestilling-wrap pb19">

                        <div class="bestilling__col">
                            <i>@Html.Raw(string.Format(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("AmendingAndCancellation"), cartInfo.CancellationInsurancePrice))</i>
                            <div class="row-sel">
                                <div class="inp">
                                    <select class="select-inp" tabindex="-1" title="" id="ddlCancellationInsurance" name="ddlCancellationInsurance" onchange="UpdateCartInfo()">
                                        <option value="0">@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("SelectIns"))</option>
                                        <option value="1">@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("YesPlease"))</option>
                                        <option value="2">@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("NoIns"))</option>
                                    </select>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <!--row-sel end-->
                        </div>
                        <!--bestilling__col end-->
                    </div>
                  }
                }
                <!--bestilling-wrap end-->
            </div>
            @*</form>*@

            <div class="bestilling__info">
                <div class="bestilling__info_i">
                    <p>
                        @cartInfo.DestinationText

                        <a class="btnMoreCartInfo" onclick="ShowMoreCartInfo()" href="javascript:void(0)">@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("SeeMore")) +</a>
                    </p>
                    <div class="more-text" id="MoreCartInfo">
                        <i>@Html.Raw(cartInfo.PaxAndDateInfoText)</i>
                        <div class="sub-total">
                            <div class="row">
                                <p><b>@cartInfo.AccomodationPriceText:</b> <i style="width: 70%;">@cartInfo.AccomodationDiscountText</i></p>
                                <span>@cartInfo.AccomodationPriceValue<br />
                                    <i>@cartInfo.AccomodationDiscountValue</i></span>
                            </div>
                            @{if (cartInfo.MandatoryProdObjs != null)
                              {
                                  foreach (MandatoryProdObjs mpo in cartInfo.MandatoryProdObjs)
                                  {
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p>@mpo.Caption:</p>
                                    <span>@mpo.Price</span>
                                </div>
                                  }
                              }
                            }
                            @{if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cartInfo.CleaningValue))
                              {
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p>@cartInfo.CleaningText:</p>
                                    <span>@cartInfo.CleaningValue</span>
                                </div>
                              }
                            }
                            @{if (cartInfo.IsCancellationInsuranceEnable)
                              {
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p>@cartInfo.CancellationInsurance:</p>
                                    <span class="CancellationInsurancePrice">@cartInfo.CancellationInsuranceValue</span>
                                </div>
                              }
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="total">
                    <p>@cartInfo.TotalPriceText:<a class="btnMoreTotalPrice" onclick="ShowMoreTotalPrice()" href="javascript:void(0)">@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("SeeMore")) +</a></p>
                    <span class="TotalPrice">@cartInfo.TotalPriceValue</span>
                    <div class="more-text" id="MoreTotalPrice"><i>@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("BookingFeeInclusive"))</i></div>
                </div>




            </div>

            @{ if (cartInfo.IsPaymentEnable)
               {
                   string fullPaymentCheck = "checked";
                   string partialPaymentCheck = "";
                   string totalPaymentDisplay = "none";
                   if (cartInfo.IsPartialPayment)
                   {
                       fullPaymentCheck = "";
                       partialPaymentCheck = "checked";
                       totalPaymentDisplay = "block";
                   }
                <div class="bestilling__info" style="background: #fff;">
                    <div class="bestilling__info_i" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                        <p>
                            @cartInfo.ChoosePaymentMethod

                            <a class="btnMorePaymentInfo" style="padding-bottom: 5px;" onclick="ShowMorePaymentInfo()" href="javascript:void(0)">@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("SeeMore")) -</a>
                        </p>
                        <div class="more-text payment-info" id="MorePaymentInfo" style="display: block">
                            @{ if (cartInfo.ChkFullPayment && cartInfo.ChkInstallmentPayment)
                               {
                                <span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkFullPayment" name="chkFullPayment" @fullPaymentCheck onchange="FullPayment()">
                                    <b style="vertical-align: super;" class="FullPaymentText">@cartInfo.FullPaymentText</b><br>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="chkFirstPayment" name="chkFirstPayment" onchange="FirstPayment()" @partialPaymentCheck>
                                    <b style="vertical-align: super;" class="InstallmentPaymentText">@cartInfo.InstallmentPaymentText</b>
                                </span>
                               }
                            }
                            <div class="sub-total">

                                <div class="row pnlTotalPrice" style="display: @totalPaymentDisplay;">
                                    <p>@cartInfo.TotalPriceText:</p>
                                    <span class="TotalPrice">@cartInfo.TotalPriceValue</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p>@cartInfo.PaymentPriceText:</p>
                                    <span class="PaymentPriceValue">@cartInfo.PaymentPriceValue</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p class="CardFeeText">@cartInfo.CardFeeText:</p>
                                    <span class="CardFeeValue">@cartInfo.CardFeeValue</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <p class="FirstPaymentText">@cartInfo.FirstPaymentText:</p>
                                    <span class="FirstPaymentValue">@cartInfo.FirstPaymentValue</span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                            <div style="padding-top: 10px;">
                                <p>
                                    @cartInfo.ChoosePayment:
                                </p>

                                <div class="row-sel">
                                    <div class="inp">
                                        <select class="select-inp" tabindex="-1" title="" id="ddlCardTypes" name="ddlCardTypes" onchange="UpdateCartInfo()">
                                            @{ foreach (CardTypes type in cartInfo.CardTypes)
                                               {
                                                <option value="@type.Value">@type.Text</option>
                                               }
                                            }
                                        </select>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
               }
            }

            <div class="bestilling__info" style="padding: 14px 0px;">
                <div class="bestilling__info_btn">
                    <a class="btn btn_green" onclick="SaveBooking()" id="btnSave" href='javascript:void(0)'>@Html.Raw(DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("Book"))</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--bestilling__info end-->
    </div>
}
<div class="Progress_Layout" style="display: none;">
    <div class="Progress_Content">
        <div>
            <img src="@Url.FilePath(FileTypes.IMAGES, "loader", "10271456A2B3")" style="vertical-align: middle" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="Progress_Text">
            @DffUtility.GetGlobalResource("pleaseWait")
        </div>
    </div>
</div>







 <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    First Page
                </h3>




                <a class="ui-btn-right showNextPage">Next</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">


                <p>1st List Example:</p>
<ol>
<li>HTML Examples</li>
<li>HTML Tutorial</li>
<li>HTML Codes</li>
<li>and much more!</li>
</ol>
            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div> 
        <div data-role="page" id="second" data-theme="a" >
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Second Page
                </h3>



                <a class="ui-btn-left showPrevPage">Back</a>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                 <p>Image  Example:</p>
<p>Second List Example:</p>
<ol>
<li>HTML Examples</li>
<li>HTML Tutorial</li>
<li>HTML Codes</li>
<li>and much more!</li>
</ol>

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

            </div>
        </div>
```

Product View:

```
@{
    Layout = ViewBag.Layout;
}
<script type="text/javascript">

    PAGE_TYPE = @DffUtility.PageType,
    BASIC_PARA = '@(Html.Raw(DffUtility.Basic_QueryString))'



</script>

@section head{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SEARCH_HEAD)
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SEARCH_SCRIPT)

    @Url.ScriptRender(BundleResources.WOWSLIDER_SCRIPT)
    @Url.ScriptRender(BundleResources.SOCIAL_SCRIPT)
}

@section header{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.SEARCH_HTML)
    @Html.Partial("PriceCalculation")
}
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.HTML)

@section footer{
    @Url.CssRender(BundleResources.WOWSLIDER_CSS)
}
```

Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Title)</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta id="descriptionTag" name="description" content="@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.Description)" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW" />
    <meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOHTMLINDEX" />
    <link href="@Url.FilePath(FileTypes.IMAGES, "favicon", "C3AC16EE6772")" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

    <style>
         @{ string  basefontpath = ConfigurationSettings.HOST + Url.Content("~/Resources/") + "fonts/";
        }
        @@font-face { font-family: 'TradeGothicLTStdBold'; src: url("@(basefontpath + "TradeGothicLTStdBold.eot")"); src: url("@(basefontpath + "TradeGothicLTStdBold.eot")") format("embedded-opentype"), url("@(basefontpath + "TradeGothicLTStdBold.woff2")") format("woff2"), url("@(basefontpath + "TradeGothicLTStdBold.woff")") format("woff"), url("@(basefontpath + "TradeGothicLTStdBold.ttf")") format("truetype"), url("@(basefontpath + "TradeGothicLTStdBold.svg#TradeGothicLTStdBold")") format("svg"); }
        @@font-face { font-family: 'ITCAvantGardeStdMd'; src: url("@(basefontpath + "ITCAvantGardeStdMd.eot")"); src: url("@(basefontpath + "ITCAvantGardeStdMd.eot")") format("embedded-opentype"), url("@(basefontpath + "ITCAvantGardeStdMd.woff2")") format("woff2"), url("@(basefontpath + "ITCAvantGardeStdMd.woff")") format("woff"), url("@(basefontpath + "ITCAvantGardeStdMd.ttf")") format("truetype"), url("@(basefontpath + "ITCAvantGardeStdMd.svg#ITCAvantGardeStdMd")") format("svg"); }

        @@font-face {font-family: 'Droid Sans';font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;src: local('Droid Sans'), local('DroidSans'), url("@(basefontpath + "s-BiyweUPV0v-yRb-cjciL3hpw3pgy2gAi-Ip7WPMi0.woff")") format('woff');}
        @@font-face {font-family: 'Droid Sans';font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;src: local('Droid Sans Bold'), local('DroidSans-Bold'), url("@(basefontpath + "EFpQQyG9GqCrobXxL-KRMXbFhgvWbfSbdVg11QabG8w.woff")") format('woff');
        @@font-face {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-style: normal;font-weight: 400;src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url("@(basefontpath + "cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3bO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff")") format('woff');}
        @@font-face {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-style: normal;font-weight: 700;src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url("@(basefontpath + "k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzKRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff")") format('woff');}
        @@font-face {font-family: 'Open Sans';font-style: normal;font-weight: 600;src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url("@(basefontpath + "MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSqRDOzjiPcYnFooOUGCOsRk.woff")") format('woff');}
}
    </style>
    @{
        @Url.ScriptRender(BundleResources.BASIC_SCRIPT)
        @Url.CssRender(BundleResources.BASIC_CSS)
    }
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)


    <script type="text/javascript">

        src = "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"
        src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"
      $(document).on('click', '.showNextPage', function() {
        $.mobile.navigate('#second', {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.showPrevPage', function() {
        $.mobile.navigate("#index", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    });
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="fri-col-sm-1 ">
            <a class="arr-prev" href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
        <div class="fri-col-sm-7 ">
            <a class="logo" href="@ViewBag.Site">
                <img src="@Url.FilePath(FileTypes.IMAGES, "logo", "AC9A5300E0D9")" alt="friferie" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="fri-col-sm-1 ">
           @*@(Html.RenderControl<Menu>("~/Menu/Menu.ascx", x => { x.MENU_NAV = SharePointServiceHelper.GetAllNavigationTerms(); x.MENU_ISMOBILE = DffUtility.IsMobile; x.MENU_PATH = Url.Content("~"); x.MENU_CSS = Url.FilePath(FileTypes.CSS, "Menu", "C7FC02E3E231"); x.MENU_JS = Url.FilePath(FileTypes.JS, "menu", "FAA6A2464B43"); x.MENU_ICON = Url.FilePath(FileTypes.IMAGES, "menu", "4A01DD1145F6"); x.MENU_EXTRACLASS = "menu-icon"; }))*@
        </div>
        <div class="clear-both"></div>
         @RenderSection("header", required: false)
    </header>
    <div class="content">

        <div class="ferie-home">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        @*@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Footer)*@

    </div>

    @RenderSection("footer", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```